# How to line up 2-by-2 equations in align environment

Tags: vertical-alignment

I know how to line up equations by "=", with each line containing only one equation. But suppose I have a 2-by-2 equation matrix, and I want two equations in each column lined up by their "=". What should I do? I tried the below, but failed.

```
\begin{align*}
a & =x+y, \; b & =x-y\\
c & =x*y  \; d & =x/y
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Use `&` instead of `\;` to change the column.

Comment: I tried it. But the two resulted columns fall unreasonably apart.

Comment: Each new group in an alignment is introduced by `&`, in supplement to the `&` used for the alignment point.

Comment: @JieWei, so you want to reduce the space between the 2 columns?

Comment: @Sigur Right. Just leave space of 2 letter width in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [two] one `aligned` inside a single `equation` (or `equation*` or `\[ \]`for  unnumbered).

**edit:** as commented by @Werner, a single `aligned` is enough.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{lipsum} %% dummy text

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned} 
a &= x + y,    & b &= x - y, \\ 
c &= x \ast y, & d &= x / y. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A single `aligned` would also suffice.

Comment: @Werner, in this case, how to align the right pair of equal signs, with reduced space between the columns?

Comment: ``\begin{aligned} a &= x + y & b &= x - y \\ c &= x \times y, & d &= x \div y. \end{aligned}``

Comment: @Werner, ow, nice. I'll edit. I didn't know that the column spaces are different when using `aligned` and `align`.

Comment: It works out well with `aligned`

Answer (score 2):

If you want control over the space between the columns, use `alignat`; here I use `\quad`, but it can be whatever spacing command you like. The only nuisance is that you have to know the widest equation or to add the spacing command to every line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} %% dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{alignat*}{2}
a &= x + y,    \quad & b &= x - y, \\ 
c &= x \ast y, \quad & d &= x / y. 
\end{alignat*}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

With `alignat` the two lines would be numbered. If you need just one number, centered with respect to the lines, use `equation` and `alignedat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} %% dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
a &= x + y,    \quad & b &= x - y, \\ 
c &= x \ast y, \quad & d &= x / y. 
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]