# How can I align 4 equations in a 2 by 2 layout while having them separately numbered?

Tags: equations, hyperref, align

I have four equations that I want to present in a 2 by 2 layout.

I found this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225318/how-to-line-up-2-by-2-equations-in-align-environment), but I would like to be able to `\cref` each equation separately and have them numbered like in this image below but aligned nicely:

[image: (edited) reference image]

Is there a way to do this or am I better off just having 4 equations below each other?

Comment: The numbers you show are a bit confusing. Do you want them to go (1) and then (2) in the first row, and then (3) and (4) in the second row, or (1) and then (2) in the left column and then (3) and then (4) in the right column? (The latter is easier.)

Comment: Yes the last reference is supposed to be (4)

Comment: It wasn't a yes or no question, and both options would lead to the "last reference" being (4), so can you clarify please?

Comment: Oh wow my bad. The latter is fine as well if it's easier.

Comment: Now that you have seen how to do this, I recommend you to think again if it is a good thing to do. It is breaking the logical structure of right-aligned equation numbers, and potential give the reader a headache, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with two `minipage`s, each with its own `align` environment.

[image]

I made the left `minipage` 40% of `\textwidth` and the right 60%, but you can adjust that how you like. For example, with `.5\textwidth` on both minipages it looks like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]


\noindent\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
  \begin{align}
    x&=1 \\
    y&=1
  \end{align}
\end{minipage}% <-- % symbol necessary
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
  \begin{align}
    z&=1\\
    w&=1
  \end{align}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Also, as @frabjous suggested in the comments, you could make smaller `minipage`s and `center` them to get the labels closer:

[image]

```
\noindent\begin{center}\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
  \begin{align}
    x&=1 \\
    y&=1
  \end{align}
\end{minipage}\hspace{1cm}% <-- % symbol necessary
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
  \begin{align}
    z&=1\\
    w&=1
  \end{align}
\end{minipage}\end{center}
```

Comment: Just to add to this, if you want the sets closer together (as in the image in the question), you could make the minipages smaller and put both inside a `\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}` environment.

Comment: I know the OP said this numbering was OK in the comments, but it's got me curious anyway. Can you think of an easy way to do the numbering horizontally, (1) (2) in the first row and (3) and (4) in the bottom row? Surprisingly it's not obvious to me how to do that easily and without manually adjusting the counter.

Comment: @frabjous: You could do this with 4 minipages and `equation`s instead of `align`s. But it requires some `\phantom`s if the equations have different widths to keep the alignment at the `=` signs.

Comment: It's not as easy as it sounds. Look at [this output](https://imgur.com/a/FVJRipI) that comes from [this code](https://pastebin.com/k43x82y5). With *a lot* (feels like too much) of manual intervention I got the horizontal alignments right, but the vertical alignment is also off. I could move the second row up with a negative length after \\ (more manual intervention!), but why is (7) lower than (8)?

Comment: @frabjous: It's because the minipages are center aligned (vertically). Use `\begin{minipage}[b]`. But you're right—that's a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks, that does help, but I'm still a little confused about why they'd have different heights to begin with. Both sides have similar descenders and superscripts. (I guess (5) and (6)'s minipages are different in height too, but I don't know why.)